# Cyrillic characters in R

Tags: r, rodbc

I am importing some data from a SQL database using the `RODBC` package. All Cyrillic characters unfortunately get converted to `?` marks upon importing the data into R. I tried setting `DBMSencoding='UTF-8'` while making the connection, but that did not work. I have also tried `Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "ukrainian")` but no joy so far. How can I get rid of the `?` mark and see the actual Cyrillic character?

Comment: Sounds like you're working on Windows.  You might find things work better if you switch to a different OS:  R for Windows doesn't have the greatest multi-language support.

Comment: @user2554330 Yes, I am on Windows and can't switch the OS because of other Windows dependent application running. Is there no other way?

Comment: I believe that if the local 8 bit code page supports some particular non-Ascii characters, then R won't mess them up, so you could try setting your code page to 1251 (the Cyrillic one) before starting R from the command line.  However, I've never tried that, and I don't know what other side effects it would have.